# How to loop through all values of a HashMap and print out any values containing a searched term

Tags: java, search, hashmap

I have a map:

```
private HashMap<String, CompactDisc> database;
```

Every `CompactDisc` object has an artist, and I want to have a user enter a string and search through the hash-map and print out ALL values containing the string.
So if I searched `"Jackson"`, I would get both The Jackson 5 and Michael Jackson (assuming they are in the CD).

Comment: Please show your latest failed attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for?http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/hashmap/value-search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the values of the HashMap and check if the CompactDisc's artist name contains the specified string.

```
for (CompactDisc cd : database.values()) {
    if(cd.getArtist().contains(searchString)){
        System.out.println(cd.getArtist());
    }
}
```

assuming `CompactDisk` has a `getArtist()` method that returns a String. And `searchString` is the string specified by user.

Answer (score 0):

Commons Collections provides a nice way to filter a `Collection` of objects:

```
// Set up data
String searchString = "Jackson";
HashMap<String, CompactDisc> database = new HashMap<String, CompactDisc>();
database.put("key1", new CompactDisc("Jackson 5"));
database.put("key2", new CompactDisc("Michael Jackson));
database.put("key3", new CompactDisc("Random artist"));

List<CompactDisc> values = database.values();
CollectionUtils.filter(values , new Predicate<CompactDisc>(){
   public boolean evaluate( CompactDisc obj ) {
     return obj.getArtist().contains(searchString);
   }
  });
```

Given `searchString` = "Jackson", after invoking `.filter` the `values` list will contain only `CompactDiscs` with artists containing "Jackson".